# SharedPreferences: What are they shared with?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I find the name of stored preferences on Android (`SharedPreferences`) to be a tad confusing. It was probably chosen with a purpose, so how exactly are these preferences *shared*? e.g. I don't want other applications accessing my app's information willy-nilly.

What is the difference between preferences from `getPreferences()` and preferences from `getSharedPreferences()`, and what is the difference between the different modes? How should I choose which to use? (Heck, if I have a multi-activity program, will using just the regular getPreferences be detrimental?)

My imagination regarding the use of these things is still pretty limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It was probably chosen with a purpose, so how exactly are these preferences shared?

They are shared among all components of your application (e.g., all of your activities).

> e.g. I don't want other applications accessing my app's information willy-nilly.

`SharedPreferences` are private to your application by default.

> What is the difference between preferences from getPreferences() and preferences from getSharedPreferences(), and what is the difference between the different modes? How should I choose which to use? (Heck, if I have a multi-activity program, will using just the regular getPreferences be detrimental?)

I am not quite certain what you are referring to, since you provided just bare method names with no classes. If you are intending on collecting preference values from the user via the preference screen system, [use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29). I generally use that for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Sharedprefernce are basically key,value pairs with can are saved in an xml and is accessible by an application. You can use it to save some setting value or default values or any other form of key value pairs.
So a key,value pair can be saved in one activity can be accessed in other activity.

Different modes means that whether the data saved can be used by other application or not. You should not worry about all modes. As MODE_WORLD_READABLE & MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE are deprecated now.

For the difference:-
[Difference between getShared/get preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)